# Access 2000 doesn't start

Tags: microsoft-office, crash, microsoft-access, office-2000

I have 3 identical new HP laptops, on which I have installed a fresh (legal) instance of Windows XP SP3 32bit from an original media, and a legal copy of Microsoft Office 2000 SR-1 Premium, also from an original media. For Office 2000 I did a customised installation and only installed Access and Powerpoint. None of them starts on any of the new PCs.

Access crashes at start and the only technical info I can gather are:

> AppName: msaccess.exe  AppVer:
>   9.0.0.6620  Modname: unknown ModVer: 0.0.0.0  Offset: 000c030e

*Edit*: the event viewer reports an `Event ID = 1000` and the message:

> Application Failure msaccess.exe
>   9.0.0.6620 in unknown 0.0.0.0 at offset 000c030e.

The application is run as `Administrator`.

*End of Edit*.

Powerpoint also dies at the start, and Clippy comes up saying that "An irreversible error has occoured" (translating from italian). But I don't care too much about PP: I need Access though.

Windows is fully updated and the appropriate drivers are installed. vcredist is installed for versions 6.0, 2005 and 2008 of Visual C.
I tried without success to uninstall and reinstall again; I also tried to apply the Office 2000 SP3 I downloaded from the Microsoft site. No joy.

Other than these two apps, everything seems to work fine on the PCs.

I've looked for hours and I can't find any helpful tips on these crashes. Anybody has an idea of what I could try to make Access work or at least gather more details about what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to make it work:

- Uninistalled everything
  Office-related (again);
- Using `regedit`
  I tried to delete all of the Office
  registry keys: I found
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office`.
  When I tried to delete it and its
  children, one node wouldn't go away
  (`b7eff951-e52f-45cc-9ef7-57124f2177cc`).
  The authorizations seemed right... So
  I selected a parent node, and in the
  authorizations I made it so the
  children nodes would inherit the
  authorizations from this node. After
  this I could delete the whole `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office`
  branch;
- Reboot;
- Reinstall Office
  2000, again a customised
  installation, with the full Access,
  the Office tools and all the filters
  and converters;
- Launched Access, and
  now it works as expected.

I'm not entirely sure what I did different from the first time I installed it. Also, I tried this only on one of the three PCs mentioned in the original post. Finger crossed that the others will work as well. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you examined the event logs on the PC?  Post any errors there with Event ID.

If I recall, you also need to run the applciation as Administrator one time.  Seems I recall it makes some odd registry entries that require elevated permission.  Is the user an Administrator?

Comment: My attempts are done using the Administrator user. The Event Viewer reports an Event ID = 1000. I have updated the original post. Thanks.